# iOSアプリがビルドできない

Tags: swift, xcode

環境
Xcode 13.4.1
Swift 5.6.1

Could not launch “App Name”
failed to get the task for process 25474
と出てしまいビルドできません。

下記の記事を参考にしたら、解決したんですが根本的問題ではないような気がして質問させていただきました。
https://ios-docs.dev/process-launch-failed/

デバッグには、何も表示されていませんでした。

Comment: `Build`ができないというより`Run`ができない状態ですね。デバイスの再起動とかで治ったりしないですかね。

Comment: 治らなかったですね